# ssh rsa key login fails ssh'ing to Cisco devices after AIX updated to 7.1.102.1100 (Protocol error: expected packet type 50, got 106) - OpenSSH_7.5p1

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, security, openssh

After updating OpenSSH to new version, I am unable to log into any Cisco equipment with my RSA key that was working previous to the patch.  I can still log in to Cisco Nexus just fine with RSA key, but all other devices fail.  Can someone please assist me with a fix?  OpenSSH_7.5p1

`bash-4.3$ ssh -vvv etc-rcore-1
OpenSSH_7.5p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2p  14 Aug 2018
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/e338wj/.ssh/config
debug3: kex names ok: [diffie-hellman-group1-sha1]
debug3: kex names ok: [diffie-hellman-group1-sha1]
debug3: kex names ok: [diffie-hellman-group1-sha1]
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Failed dlopen: /usr/krb5/lib/libkrb5.a(libkrb5.a.so): Could not load module /usr/krb5/lib/libkrb5.a(libkrb5.a.so).
System error: No such file or directory`

`debug1: Error loading Kerberos, disabling Kerberos auth.
debug2: resolving "etc-rcore-1" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to etc-rcore-1 [172.28.5.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/e338wj/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/e338wj/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/e338wj/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/e338wj/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/e338wj/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/e338wj/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/e338wj/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/e338wj/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version Cisco-1.25
debug1: match: Cisco-1.25 pat Cisco-1.* compat 0x60000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to etc-rcore-1:22 as 'e338wj'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/e338wj/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/e338wj/.ssh/known_hosts:17
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from etc-rcore-1
(emitted email lines for spam filter)
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
(emitted email lines for spam filter)
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128
(omitted email lines for spam filter)
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 34
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<4096<8192) sent
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: bits set: 2060/4096
debug3: send packet: type 32
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 33
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:xxx
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/e338wj/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/e338wj/.ssh/known_hosts:17
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from etc-rcore-1
debug1: Host 'etc-rcore-1' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/e338wj/.ssh/known_hosts:17
debug2: bits set: 2076/4096
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug2: key: /home/e338wj/.ssh/id_rsa (200a1a88)
debug2: key: /home/e338wj/.ssh/id_dsa (0)
debug2: key: /home/e338wj/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0)
debug2: key: /home/e338wj/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0)
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 53
debug3: input_userauth_banner
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/e338wj/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:xxx
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:xxx
debug3: send packet: type 106
debug1: Sent ALLOW_PKCS12_KEYSTORE_CLIENT_FLAG packet
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 1
Received disconnect from 172.28.5.1 port 22:2: Protocol error: expected packet type 50, got 106
Authentication failed.`

Comment: So is it OpenSSH 7.1, or is it OpenSSH 7.5 on AIX 7.1?

Comment: Sorry it's AIX 7.1 with OpenSSH_7.5p1.  I have updated the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently caused by an IBM AIX-specific addition to OpenSSH, which sends a nonstandard message type to [unlock EFS](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-opensshefs.html) without prior agreement with the server. (I found this through other forum posts: [1](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=c58a7f46-bc76-41de-9328-cfa8095f2e4b), [2](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SSHD-886), [3](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/git-ssh-clone-error-for-a-public-repo-related/qaq-p/980734).)

(AIX OpenSSH probably does this because it's technically legal behavior as per [RFC 4253 section 11.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-11.4), which specifies that the server is supposed to only *inform* the client of unsupported message types. However, in practice many SSH server softwares have decided to be much stricter about unrecognized messages.)

To disable this feature through ~/.ssh/config, use:

```
AllowPKCS12keystoreAutoOpen no
```

Comment: I just attempted to add this to to /~/.ssh/config and it's still giving me the same error message.  No dice :(

Comment: Try to specify it using `ssh -o "AllowPKCS12keystoreAutoOpen=no"`?

Comment: That worked!  Thanks!  My ssh config must be pulling from another directory then.